# Infopath 2010 Form has to override previous form

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

I am very new to sharepoint . Got to do a job. There are 2 infopath form Form A and Form B.  when the user x logs into system and make change to form B , It overrides form A of the same user. Now my understanding of digging into sharepoint taught me it will be done by workflow. Can anyone tell me how it can be done? Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean by "override"? How does form A overrides form B?

Comment: form A will overlap form B

Comment: That doesn't make it any clearer, just more confusing. Please give us a more concrete example.